# usage of wild card like "like" in codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter, wildcard

In my codeigniter project.i have a category value 2-1-1,2-1,2....etc.how to write a query which does the deletion of category from database like 2-1-1 using like operator.

$id = '2-1';

i want to get the as result all records with category_id as '2-1' and also starting from '2-1' like '2-1-1' ,'2-1-1-2',....from database.i am getting category_id as $id.how to do this?

This is what i tried

```
this->db->select('dc.*');
        
$this->db->from('document_category as dc');
           
$this->db->like('dc.category_id', $id , 'after' OR 'dc.category_id', $id);
```

but it is not taking exact match record.how to do this?
i want to get the query of this sql

SELECT * FROM `document_category` where category_id LIKE "2-1%"

Comment: elaborate more on your question. It's very difficult to understand.

Comment: ellaborated.can u pls respond if it is not understandable.

Comment: show me your database sample dataset how `category_id` stored

Comment: its values are 2-1, 2-1-1 ,2-1-2 like varchar value

Comment: i wanted to get this sql as in the above mentioned format.SELECT * FROM document_category where category_id LIKE "2-1%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To archive this

```
SELECT * FROM document_category where category_id LIKE "2-1%"
```

Just use

```
$this->db->like('dc.category_id', $id , 'after');
```

---

Final

```
$this->db->like('category_id', $id , 'after');
$result = $this->db->get('document_category ');
```

[`like()` in codeigniter.com](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id3)

Comment: can i get category_id 2-1 from this

Comment: how to perform deletion of all records which the above mentioned logic.delete multiple recods where category_id like  '2-1%'. can you pls help.

Comment: the same way you can add.  but when deleting with `like` operator is too bad. try with column id or `where` clause with exact word